# Move Files out of Folders Python

Tags: python

I save a lot of content into a directory Q:\Move_Folder

Sometimes that content will be saved directly, such as Q:\Move_Folder\video.mkv

Most of the time it is saved automatically as this: Q:\Move_Folder\Subfolder\video.mkv

I am looking to iterate through every subfolder inside of Move_Folder, extract anything that ends with a certain file extension, and move it out of the folder, so that it is Q:\Move_Folder\video.mkv

I have run this script and it works when moving from say Q:\Completed to Q:\Move_Folder, and will move all correct file extensions, but when doing it from within Q:\Move_Folder I am currently returned no error, but no files are moved either:

Code:

```
import os
import os.path
import shutil

target = r'Q:\Move_Folder'

ext = ['.mkv', '.mp4','.avi','.srt','.ass']
movedFiles = []

from pathlib import Path
rootdir = Path(r"Q:\Move_Folder")
os.path.isfile(rootdir)


for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if rootdir.is_dir():
            pass
        else:
            file.endswith(tuple(ext))
            movedFiles.append(file)
            fullfile = os.path.join(subdir, file)
            shutil.move(fullfile, target)
            print("FileMoved: " + file)
```

Going to add the final product below if anyone has any similar type of need, I think this is quite useful. Tested it, and it works for what I want.

```
import os
import os.path
import shutil

from pathlib import Path

# Setting all variables
target = r'Q:\Move_Folder'
deletedFiles = []
# If you don't have .r00-.r09 here they will not be deleted, because numbers do not
# increment as 00-09 they increment as 0-9
r = ['.r00', '.r01', '.r02', '.r03', '.r04', '.r05', '.r06', '.r07', '.r08', '.r09']
ext2 = ['.nfo', '.jpg', '.rar', '.jpg', '.png', '.sfv', '.NFO']
rootdirss = r"Q:\Move_Folder"
x = 00
ext = ('.mkv', '.mp4','.avi','.srt','.ass')
movedFiles = []
rootdir = Path(target)

# Search for Files that I want to keep, and move them to Move_Folder out of their pre-existing folder
for file in rootdir.rglob("*"):
    if file.name.endswith(ext) and file.parent != rootdir:
        print(file.parent)
        movedFiles.append(file)
        file.rename(rootdir / file.name)
        print("File Moved To Move_Folder: " + file.name)

# Iterate through x which is for .r00 files, adding them 
# to .r00 through .r150 for deleting purposes.
while x < 150:
    r.append(".r" + str(x))
    x += 1

# Main content for deleting junk, will first iterate through ext for normal file extensions
# Then will iterate through .r00 files and deleting them
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdirss):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(tuple(ext2)):
            deletedFiles.append(file)
            os.remove(os.path.join(subdir, file))
            print("Deleted: " + file)
        # Begin of deleting .r00 files    
        for i in r:
            if file.endswith(i):
                deletedFiles.append(file)
                os.remove(os.path.join(subdir, file))
                print("Deleted: " + file)        

# Search for any directories (Folders), and delete them
for dir in rootdir.rglob('*'):
    if dir.name.endswith(ext):
        pass
    else:
        print("Deleting Folder: ", dir)
        shutil.rmtree(dir)
```

Comment: why the `if rootdir.is_dir(): pass`? You **know** it's a directory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already made the first good step of using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob), why not go all the way? See how simple it is:

```py
from pathlib import Path

target = r'Q:\Move_Folder'

ext = ('.mkv', '.mp4','.avi','.srt','.ass')
movedFiles = []

rootdir = Path(target)

for file in rootdir.rglob("*"):
    if file.name.endswith(ext) and file.parent != rootdir:
        movedFiles.append(file)
        file.rename(rootdir / file.name)
        print("FileMoved: " + file.name)
```

`pathlib` is very useful and powerful when working with paths. In most use-cases I came across it was much more simple than using `os.path` equivalents and it is much more platform-safe.

Comment: I am still very new to python, only been about a week of using it, so I am still trying to learn, and these side projects I have started have been tremendous for helping me learn. 

I ran what you had sent, and i was returned an error "The Volume does not contain a recognized file system." - Please make sure that all required file system drivers are loaded and that the volume is not corrupted:

maybe I should also specify that this is a sftp mounted folder using rclone.

Comment: Interesting. What OS are you using?

Comment: I am running it on Windows, but the files are an sftp rclone mount. Q:\ is the mount location

Comment: Oh I see. Didn't got to work with that. That might be some issue with pathlib

Comment: I am going to work with what you sent, as I see a lot of good inside of it. I think what you sent, with a few alterations will get it to work for my specific need. Will edit if I get it to work.

Comment: Hope you get it to work! In general (putting the sftp aside) it is a good practice to work with `pathlib` instead of `os` related functions

Comment: So this is very very very odd, I say that with lots of confusion.

Deleted the code you put in my test script I made for it, tinkered with it, could not get it to work, messed it up so bad that i couldn't see what you had done anymore, so i re-pasted your code, exact same way as before... ran it, and it is currently running perfectly right now. You Rock!

Comment: also, will begin working with pathlib, as I do want to start learning best practices, especially during my early learning stage.

Comment: @Jordan wow. Super-weird, but happy you got it to work! Happy learning

Answer (score 0):

The first issue here is that `rootdir.is_dir()` will always be true since `Q:Move_Folder` is a directory and the value for `rootdir` is never  mutated.

You also seem to cast `ext` to a tuple when you should probably make it a tuple for the get-go unless you need to be able to add more extensions at runtime.

Additionally you aren't doing anything with the return type of `file.endswith(tuple(ext))`

You could probably simplify this into:

```py
for root, dirs, files, os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(tuple(ext)):
            shutil.move(os.path.join(root, name), target)
            print("FileMoved: " + file)
```